# Retrieving multiple fields from databse(mySQL) using Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to retrieve data from a database. I need to get multiple fields from the same row. I'm using a key to retrieve data from a single row but I get the following error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value All of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is the code:

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); //line with the error
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject ob = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = ob.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            dob = ob.getString(Config.KEY_DOB);
            gname= ob.getString(Config.KEY_GNAME);
            sem= ob.getString(Config.KEY_SEM);
...
```

The php and the Config class work fine.
I don't know how I should change the code to correct the issue. All suggestions would be helpful.

edit:
Here's the code for the entire class:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class editdata extends AppCompatActivity {

    String id =login_students.getuidp();

    EditText fn;
    EditText db;
    EditText sm;
    EditText brnch;
    EditText gnme;
    EditText em;
    EditText gpn;
    EditText mb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editdata);



        fn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        db = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);
        sm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sem);
        brnch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.branch);
        gnme=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.guardian_name);
        em = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        gpn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.parent_mobile);
        mb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);



        getData();
    }
    private void getData() {

        if (id.equals("")) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Check Detail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        
        String url = Config.DATA_URL + "id";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                showJSONS(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(editdata.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    private void showJSONS(String response) {
        String name = "";
        String dob = "";
        String sem = "";
        String branch = "";
        String email = "";

        String gname="";
        String gphn = "";
        String mob = "";



        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject ob = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = ob.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            dob = ob.getString(Config.KEY_DOB);
            gname= ob.getString(Config.KEY_GNAME);
            sem= ob.getString(Config.KEY_SEM);
            branch= ob.getString(Config.KEY_BRANCH);
            gphn= ob.getString(Config.KEY_PMOB);
            email= ob.getString(Config.KEY_EMAIL);
            mob=ob.getString(Config.KEY_MOB);




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fn.setText("" + name);
        db.setText("" + dob);
        sm.setText("" + sem);
        brnch.setText("" + branch);
        em.setText("" + email);
        gnme.setText("" + gname);
        mb.setText("" + mob);
        gpn.setText(""+ gphn);
    }
}
```

Comment: `response` is not a valid JSON string. Please, show us how it is generated.

Comment: Why not use "JsonReader" class and parse/read the String key/value_by_key/value??

Comment: @Syscall Hi, I've added the code.Please check and let me know.

Comment: @emandt Could you please show me how I should implement it?